# Bootstrap Image and paragraph aligning on left and right with columns

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem in Bootstrap 4. I am trying to align images with paragraphs so that image is in first row on left side with paragraph, on second row image is on right side with the paragraph on left, third row image is on left side with paragraph on right side, I want to make it responsive on all devices but, Medium size devices align first and second image in one row and I dont know how to fix it.

So basicaly what I am doing is hiding images on large screens and showing them on smaller screens.

Here is my code so you can see what is going on:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-size lead col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 float-right">
            <p class="ml-auto"><h1>Heading/h1>In in lectus vel sapien pellentesque euismod a in sapien. Praesent auctor odio ut condimentum pulvinar. Vivamus in feugiat lectus. Morbi risus nulla, mattis vitae massa eget, sodales fringilla nisl. Praesent eget hendrerit turpis. Sed aliquam luctus sapien, a tempus tortor consequat eget.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block"><img srcset="images/img1.jpg" width="300px" alt="Image" id="imgDest" class="img-fluid rounded pull-right">
        </div>
        <div class="d-md-none"><img srcset="images/img1.jpg" width="300px" alt="Image" id="imgDest" class="img-fluid rounded pull-right">
        </div>

        <div class="d-none d-md-block"><img srcset="images/img2.jpg" width="300px" alt="Image 2" id="imgDest" class="img-fluid rounded pull-right">
        </div>
        <div class="text-size lead col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 float-right">
            <p class="ml-auto"><h1>Heading</h1>In in lectus vel sapien pellentesque euismod a in sapien. Praesent auctor odio ut condimentum pulvinar. Vivamus in feugiat lectus. Morbi risus nulla, mattis vitae massa eget, sodales fringilla nisl. Praesent eget hendrerit turpis. Sed aliquam luctus sapien, a tempus tortor consequat eget.</p>

        </div>
        <div class="d-md-none"><img srcset="images/image2.jpg" width="300px" alt="Image 2" id="imgDest" class="img-fluid rounded pull-right">
        </div>

        <div class="text-size lead col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 float-right">
            <p class=""><h1>Heading 3</h1>In in lectus vel sapien pellentesque euismod a in sapien. Praesent auctor odio ut condimentum pulvinar. Vivamus in feugiat lectus. Morbi risus nulla, mattis vitae massa eget, sodales fringilla nisl. Praesent eget hendrerit turpis. Sed aliquam luctus sapien, a tempus tortor consequat eget.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="d-none d-md-block"><img srcset="images/img3.jpg" width="300px" alt="Image 3" id="imgDest" class="img-fluid rounded pull-right">
        </div>
        <div class="d-md-none"><img srcset="images/img3.jpg" width="300px" alt="Image 3" id="imgDest" class="img-fluid rounded pull-right">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And is there another way to do that without using hidden images to load on other devices?

Answer (score 0):

Use column order class of bootstrap to position the images and paragraphs based on screen sizes. Here is the [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/) that might help.